# Python modify an xml file

Tags: python, xml, addition

I have this xml model.

[link text](http://www.2shared.com/document/CskJQhS6/model_template.html)

So I have to add some node (see the text commented) to this file.
How I can do it?

I have writed this partial code but it doesn't work:

```
xmldoc=minidom.parse(directory)
child = xmldoc.createElement("map")
for node in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Environment"):
    node.appendChild(child)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dead link with the xml model. maybe you could post the relevant part of it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your sample xml file and your code works fine. Your problem is most likely with the line: `xmldoc=minidom.parse(directory)`, should this not be the path to the file you are trying to parse not to a directory? The `parse()` function parses an XML file it does **not** automatically parse all the XML files in a given directory.

If you change your code to something like below this should work fine:

```
xmldoc=minidom.parse("directory/model_template.xml")
child = xmldoc.createElement("map")
    for node in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Environment"):
        node.appendChild(child)
```

If you then execute the statement: `print xmldoc.toxml()` you will see that the `map` element has indeed been added to the `Environment` element: `<Environment><map/></Environment>`.

Comment: If it turns out the file is semi-corrupt, you can try using BeautifulStoneSoup.

Comment: Agreed, but in this case it was not necessary.