# Modifying an XML File - Dividing values

Tags: python, xml, lxml, sld

I am looking to modify certainly values with in a xml file by dividing them.

I need to divide the values for `se:SvgParameter[name="stroke-width"]` and `se:Size` by 3.6. I found this tutorial on Python.org, [Modifying an XML File](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file), but it doesn’t seem to work and I couldn’t find something similar on here. Any help or point would be greatly appreciated!

Here's some example XML, but I want to be able to output the script in a folder with multiple files and have it convert all of them.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.1.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem</se:Name>
    <se:Description>
      <se:Title>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem</se:Title>
      <se:Abstract>This SLD is in Pixels, but QGIS will read it as mm</se:Abstract>
    </se:Description>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem_Line</se:Name>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Name>Line</se:Name>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">36</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem_Point</se:Name>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Name>Point</se:Name>
            <se:Graphic>
             <se:Mark>
              <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
              <se:Fill>
               <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#FF0000</se:SvgParameter>
              </se:Fill>
             </se:Mark>
             <se:Size>36</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

tree = ET.parse('QGIS-SLD-ScaleProblem_Line.sld')
root = tree.getroot()

# To check that the script is reading the correct file
print("SLD file", root[0][0].text, "loaded.")

# Registers namespaces to prevent them being filled with defaults
ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.opengis.net/sld")
ET.register_namespace('ogc', "http://www.opengis.net/ogc")
ET.register_namespace('xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
ET.register_namespace('xlink', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
ET.register_namespace('schemaLocation', "http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd")
ET.register_namespace('se', "http://www.opengis.net/se")

# This section "should" search the XML for se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width" and se:Size and divide the value by 3.6
for SvgParameter in root.iter('SvgParameter'):
    new_SvgParameter = int(SvgParameter.text) / 3.6
    SvgParameter.text = str(new_SvgParameter)
for Size in root.iter('Size'):
    new_Size= int(Size.text) / 3.6
    Size.text = str(new_Size)

tree.write("GIS-SLD-ScaleFixed.sld", xml_declaration=True, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Answers I’ve looked at:

- [How to update/modify a XML file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591579/how-to-update-modify-a-xml-file-in-python)
- [Editing values in a xml file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849976/editing-values-in-a-xml-file-with-python)
- [Python: Modifying an XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487654/python-modifying-an-xml-file)
- [Modifying an XML File in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213895/modifying-an-xml-file-in-python)
- [Python modify an xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836132/python-modify-an-xml-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. And Python's `lxml` module can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. Plus XSLT can be run outside Python, hence its portability.

Simply call the [identity transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy whole document as is and then run the division on selected nodes. No `for` loops or `if` logic needed with this approach.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special well-formed XML file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">                               
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="se:SvgParameter[@name='stroke-width']|se:Size">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(text(), '#') div 3.6"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(iterate below process in loop for multiple files)*

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(doc)

# OUTPUT TO SCREEN    
print(result)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem</se:Name>
    <se:Description>
      <se:Title>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem</se:Title>
      <se:Abstract>This SLD is in Pixels, but QGIS will read it as mm</se:Abstract>
    </se:Description>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem_Line</se:Name>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Name>Line</se:Name>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">10</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>QGIS_SLD_ScaleProblem_Point</se:Name>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Name>Point</se:Name>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#FF0000</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>10</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Thank You! This is exactly what I was after! I guess I need to learn more about XSLT!